# Combinination of Linked-list and Array

Tags: arrays, list, arraylist, linked-list

I want a data structure that be combination of linked-list and array. Actually I need random access attribute while I don't know the exact number of elements.

Now have you any suggestion for this problem? Is there any data structure for this purpose?

Edit:
How we can create a dynamic tree,too?

Finally I want a tree like this:

[image]

Shape of each node is `<key,value>`. As well as the tree is dynamic and each node can have various number of children.

Comment: how about a dynamic array or a linked list with random access? what language is it?

Comment: well this is my question! how I can have a dynamic data structure with random access attribute?? I have no idea about this...

Comment: make one... in C# you can use the simple List<T> but i don't know what language are you using???

Comment: I did't decide about the language. I have an algorithm and I am search about the ways that can help me to implement it... If really C# has this feature,well it's good! Can you explain more about it?

Comment: sure, i'll put it in an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using C# you can use `List<T>`.

for example if i want a list of integers i'll do:

```csharp
     List<int> lst = new List<int>();
     lst.Add(3);
     lst.Add(1);
     lst.Add(10);
     lst.Add(32);
     lst.Remove(1);

     lst[2] = 4;

     int x = lst[1];
```

this is an example of what you can do with a list in c#. if you need any more help just ask

for building a tree it's just a matter of creating a class containing a list of it's own children and maybe a parent:

```csharp
public class TreeNode
{
   private TreeNode parent;
   private List<TreeNode> children;
}
```

Comment: Well! your guidance was absolutely useful! It was exactly such a answer that I was expected! Now can you guide me that how can I build a tree that each node of it has `List` type? (i.e. A tree that each node in it can have various number and dynamic children)

Comment: @Dear "No Idea For Name", I updated the question and upload a photo of the tree that I want create it. I read your comment about creating tree but I could not create this my tree, I think I need more details. I will be so happy if you guide me in more detail...